# Google analytics viewing access by userID

Tags: google-analytics, userid, user-tracking

I have asked this question several times over on the GA forum, but no result.  So maybe you guys can help...

I have set up google analytics with userIds on various pages of a site, with the aim of identifying exactly which pages are looked at by which users.  So, sending GA the string 
 ga('create', 'UA-39536320-1', {'userId': '1001'});
means GA keeps track of all accesses by user 1001, and I can then (in theory) track all pages looked at by this user.

Trouble is, GA reporting seems to offer no out-of-the-box way of doing this.  Indeed, some of the reporting features supposedly enabled by GA with userIds just don't seem to be available (eg coverage; user engagement; etc).

Am I the only one trying to do this? Seems other people have achieved a similar result using custom variables; do I have to do that, and give up on GA userIds?

Comment: I also send it as a custom dimension. Then you can see it.  I suspect that Userid is used internally for some random Google magic but haven't been able to find the magic yet.

Answer (score 0):

The [userId feature](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/user-id) can be used in conjunction with a [user id enabled view (profile)](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123669?hl=en) to analyze cross device sessions.

As pointed out by DalmTo it is possible to use custom dimensions to track any non PII information about a user. [This article here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/data-import-user) gives a good example combining sending user scoped custom dimensions along with imported CRM user data to analyze and segments users for remarketing purposes.

Comment: OK... so what I am doing now is:

Comment: OK... so what I am doing now is: setting up two custom dimensions in admin.  These are: client, index 1, user scope; book, index 2, hit scope. I'm then inserting these statements into the tracking code: ga('set', 'dimension1', 'user1'); and ga('set', 'dimension2', 'book1');.  Now if I understand this correctly: in GA reporting if I go to Reporting by Custom Variables I should now see the hits for user 1 on book 1... Only I do not seem to be seeing this.